# Which Algorithm to reduce multiple lists (finding the villains)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm sure this algorithm is used in many areas but i can't find the appropriate name or algorithm, so here is the problem to be solved :

> Let's say we have a town and we want to sort out the villains, we know exactly how many there are, but we don't know them, although we have some probabilities and lists in which we know exactly how many villains it contains among other people

let's take this example :

```
L1 -> [S1, S3, S5, S6]
L2 -> [S1, S2, S6, S5]
L3 -> [S2]
L4 -> [S2, S3]
```

We know that :

```
L1 has 1 suspect
L2 has 1 suspect
L3 has 0 suspects
L4 has 0 suspects
```

- Lists can contain similar elements.
- There are many villains and can appear on the same list

Based on this simple example, we can determine that the villain is S1.

The similar algorithm that i could find is Hopcroft-Karp bipartite matching (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hopcroftkarp/1.2.3), but it seems that it solves a similar problem but not this particular one.

Comment: That sounds NP-complete. If you had "at least one villain" instead of "exactly one villain" constraints, I would have a straightforward reduction from SAT to show you. I'm not sure if it's NP-complete with the exact villain counts, but it feels like it should be.

Comment: @user2357112 : a list can contain multiple villains as you described :
There are many villains and can appear on the same list

Comment: If it is NP-complete it is fixed parameter tractable, in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity because if there are only very small numbers of villains you can always try all choices of small numbers of villains in tractable time. In the easiest case there is just one villain so just try all suspects.

Comment: Sounds like a generalization of [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)).

Comment: The problem is definitely NP-complete if it's possible for the suspect lists to not uniquely identify the villains. I have a straightforward reduction from the exact cover problem. I'm not sure whether it'd change things if the suspect lists always exactly determine the villains.

Comment: How did you conclude that the villain is S1? If you remove S2 and S3 from L1 and L2, you're left with identical lists containing S1,S5, and S6. I see no way to conclude that S1 is the villain from that information.

Comment: Might be worth comparing with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability "the problem is to determine whether there exists a truth assignment to the variables so that each clause has exactly one TRUE literal....One-in-three 3-SAT, together with its positive case, is listed as NP-complete problem"